# SSIS project has green arrow on the name

Tags: ssis

I just imported an SSIS project into a solution that already contains an SSRS report project.  The SSIS project has a small green arrow next to it.  What does this mean? 
Also the project name is followed by the text *(package deployment model)*

[image]

Comment: Right click on the Solution and Add new Project and select SSIS (this will create a project deployment model SSIS project vs your package deployment model) Does it use the same decorator on the project? It feels like this (plus the red checkmark on the Solution) is an overlay from your source control tooling

Comment: Yeah, probably means it's checked out.

Comment: @billinkc, after doing this, with the default deployment model being project, I switched it to package deployment, and the green arrow was applied.  so, its an indication of the deployment type and nothing to do with the source control status.

Answer (score 1):

credit to billinkc for his suggestion - its an indication that the project is using the ***package*** deployment model, rather than the default ***project*** deployment model.